# installing package using CPAN Perl

Tags: perl, xampp

I'm trying to install some libraries using `Perl` from the command line:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install XML::Tidy"
```

However, I'm not being able to:

```
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running Build test
t\00pod.t ..... ok
t\00podc.t .... Can't locate Test/Pod/Coverage.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:\xam
pp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib C:\xampp\perl\bin\
.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\arch C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/pe
rl/site/lib .) at t\00podc.t line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t\00podc.t line 1.
t\00podc.t .... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t\00small.t ... Base class package "XML::XPath" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
    or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpa
n\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-
Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\arch C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib .).
 at C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib/XML/Tidy
.pm line 5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12
.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib/XML/Tidy.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at t\00small.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t\00small.t line 3.
t\00small.t ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 15/15 subtests
t\01medium.t .. Base class package "XML::XPath" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
    or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpa
n\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-
Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\arch C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib .).
 at C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib/XML/Tidy
.pm line 5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12
.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib/XML/Tidy.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at t\01medium.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t\01medium.t line 3.
t\01medium.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 15/15 subtests
t\02large.t ... Base class package "XML::XPath" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
    or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpa
n\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-
Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\arch C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib .).
 at C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib/XML/Tidy
.pm line 5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12
.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib/XML/Tidy.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at t\02large.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t\02large.t line 3.
t\02large.t ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 15/15 subtests
t\03prune.t ... Base class package "XML::XPath" is empty.
    (Perhaps you need to 'use' the module which defines that package first,
    or make that module available in @INC (@INC contains: C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpa
n\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-
Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\arch C:/xampp/perl/lib C:/xampp/perl/site/lib .).
 at C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib/XML/Tidy
.pm line 5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\xampp\perl\bin\.cpan\build\XML-Tidy-1.12
.B55J2qn-y5sVpz\blib\lib/XML/Tidy.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at t\03prune.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t\03prune.t line 3.
t\03prune.t ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 15/15 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t\00podc.t  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t\00small.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 15 tests but ran 0.
t\01medium.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 15 tests but ran 0.
t\02large.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 15 tests but ran 0.
t\03prune.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 15 tests but ran 0.
Files=6, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.09 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 5/6 test programs. 0/2 subtests failed.
  PIP/XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn.tgz
  C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PIP/XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn.tgz
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent stat
e
Running Build install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

In fact, I haven't been able to install any library (`YAML` for example). I also tried someone's suggestion:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->force(qw(XML::Tidy));"
```

However I had the same outcome. Could someone please help me to figure out how to install those packages? I'm running `Perl` in a `Windows 7` machine.

Comment: Is it Strawberry or ActivePerl? If latter, I recommend using their own solution (PPM) to install the CPAN modules.

Comment: I'm using `Perl` which came with `xampp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix earlier errors first! [`XML::Tidy`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTidy) has a stated dependency on [`Test::Pod::Coverage`](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aPod%3a%3aCoverage) and [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aXPath). You don't have them installed, so an error must have occurred earlier in the installation process.

Comment: That one was fixed ... I also installed `YAML` using `ppm`. However the errors persist.

Comment: @philippe Actually you didn't have to install `YAML`; ikegami named the modules that are actually dependencies of `XML::Tidy`.